# Firebug kind of library/control (php/java/.net) to use in my application

Tags: java, php, .net, firebug

Is there any PHP/.NET/Java library that I can use in my application to get final CSS styles applied to elements of a web page (after css and js are executed). For example I want to get text color of the `<p class="summary">` in a loaded HTML page.

Is there a firebug kind of library/control  (php/java/.net) to use in my application. No UI is neccessary though.

Comment: "For example I want to get text color of the in a loaded HTML page."??????

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need a web browser for this. You may want to look into embedding options of web browsers (UI-less, I guess), or you could go the easy route and implement it as e.g. a Chrome or Firefox extension right away; essentially running inside the browser and having the browser do all the parsing and CSS work for you.